# Plesk: How to create an email account for a subdomain?

Tags: plesk

I just created a subdomain with Plesk (let say, sub.example.com) but now I am not able to create email accounts for that subdomain (ex. contact@sub.example.com)

The button "Email Addresses" is missing in all subdomain panels.
Going through the main "Mail" option in not useful: under "Mail->Create Email Address" there are no options for any subdomain.

Answer (score 1):

**Using the GUI**

It is possible to create email accounts for subdomains using the Plesk GUI,
but the subdomain *must be registered in Plesk as a new domain* and not as a new subdomain.

Intuitively users will register subdomains using the "Add Subdomain" button and not then "Add Domain" button, however for Plesk there is a conceptual difference between these two cases.

**Using the command line**

(Only available for Windows) You can use the `mail.exe` command:

```
cd plek_folder
mail.exe --create user@sub.example.com -passwd some_password -mailbox true
```

**Comments**

In both solution it is mandatory to make a new subscription for the subdomain.
In contrast, with CPanel it is possible to create email addresses for domains and subdomains without an actual subscription.

There are two user requests related with this topic in User Voice:

- PPP-6799: email addresses for subdomains are necessary - why this is
  not implemented as a standard [[1](https://plesk.uservoice.com/forums/184549-feature-suggestions/suggestions/15714789-ppp-6799)].
- Make subdomain email addresses possible without new subscription [[2](https://plesk.uservoice.com/forums/184549-feature-suggestions/suggestions/5469668-make-subdomain-email-addresses-possible-without-ne)].